# Refactor java static method to make it testable

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, refactoring, static-methods

I want to make this code testable but the `URI` and `File` instance created inside the method are giving me problems. I am not able to define mock behavior for them and I don't want to use PowerMock because they don't reflect on Jacoco's test coverage. 
If possible can we refactor the code somehow. It would be preferable if we could retain the static nature of the method. As changing that, would mess other parts of the code.

```java
public static List<String> getAbsoluteFilePaths(String dirUrl) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI(dirUrl);
        File folder = new File(uri);
        File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

        if (fileList != null) {
            for (File file : fileList) {
                String fileOrDirUrl = uri.getScheme() + "://" +
                        (uri.getAuthority() != null ? uri.getAuthority() : "")+
                        file.getAbsolutePath();

                if (file.isFile())
                    fileNames.add(fileOrDirUrl);
                else if (file.isDirectory())
                    fileNames.addAll(getAbsoluteFilePaths(fileOrDirUrl));
            }
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
```

Comment: `but the URI and File instance created inside the method are giving me problems.` - What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the question if it's useful in this case to mock `File` and `URI` you could extract the creation of an object via a functional interface.

```java
    private static final Function<String, File> fileFactory = File::new;
    
    public static List<String> getAbsoluteFilePaths(String dirUrl) throws URISyntaxException {
        File folder = fileFactory.apply(dirUrl);
        
        URI uri = folder.toURI();
        File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

        if (fileList != null) {
            for (File file : fileList) {
                String fileOrDirUrl = uri.getScheme() + "://"
                        + (uri.getAuthority() != null ? uri.getAuthority() : "")
                        + file.getAbsolutePath();

                if (file.isFile()) {
                    fileNames.add(fileOrDirUrl);
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    fileNames.addAll(getAbsoluteFilePaths(fileOrDirUrl));
                }
            }
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URI)), the used constructor of class File sets some preconditions that must be met: e.g., the URI has to be absolute, its scheme has to be 'file' and its authority has to be undefined.

Therefore, the construction of the URI can be left to method File#toURI(), so that you can split the method into two testable parts:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static List<String> getAbsoluteFilePaths(String dirUrl) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI(dirUrl);
        File folder = new File(uri);
        return getFileUris(folder);
    }
    
    public static List<String> getFileUris(File folder) {
        File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

        if (fileList != null) {
            for (File file : fileList) {
                if (file.isFile())
                    fileNames.add(file.toURI().toString());
                else if (file.isDirectory())
                    fileNames.addAll(getFileUris(file));
            }
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think I may use a fileFactory bean as mentioned by @asbachb and use dependency injection to inject that fileFactory but for this I may have to make this method non-static. But this will make the code testable I guess. What do you think @Mihe?

Comment: Of course, you can use the mapping function, too. Both approaches separate the task of creating the File object from getting the file URIs. If you want to go the static path, you can even introduce another method that expects the String and the mapping function as parameters.

Comment: @rahulsahoo You don't need the `fileFactory` to be `static final` you could add a setter or change to package protected. Would be nice to upvote and/or accept one answer.